# Displaying Multiple String Values as separate fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I'm a bit of a noob with crystal reports so be as detailed as possible.

I'm working with two fields in a report, "CRD_NAME", and "CREDIT_CARD_AMOUNT". I can right click the former to browse data and see the credit card types: AMEX, VISA, DISCVR, and MASTER. When I drag this field out to the report, it will only display one value (currently "AMEX").

When I place the Credit_card_amount field under this, it will properly display AMEX totals for that day. Browsing data on this field shows all of the CC totals, and I'm not sure how to associate them with a card type.

What I'm looking to accomplish, is to have CRD_NAME repeated in 4 columns, displaying the different CC types, and the correlating totals under each one. Do I need to create multiple parameters for each field and what I want it to represent?

Any clues would be much appreciated :)

Comment: As Douglas suggested cross tab will be the best option for this requirement. If you don't wish to use cross tabs then you need to manullay write 4 formulas and show data as per requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet might be to create a "Cross Tab" crystal report. When you create a new crystal report, cross tab is one of the options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My datasource is Retail Pro 9 on an Oracle database - so there are canned reports I'm working off of. There was in fact a subreport built in that was a cross tab. I wasn't really a fan of the data being represented in two tables hence my question :)

I ended up finding another SP that had the different CC types as their own fields which did the trick... But now I know more about cross tabs!

I am curious about how I could write 4 formulas to accomplish this, however.